# How to prove this stronger form of Cauchy Goursat's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $W$ be an open subset in $C$ and $f$ be a continuous function on $
>  W$. Let $a\in W $ and assume that $f : W \setminus \{a\} \to C$ is
> complex differentiable function. Then, for any closed rectangle $R
> \subseteq W$, we have
>
> $\int_{\partial R} f(z) = 0$

If $a $ is not inside or on our rectangle, then the result simply follows from Cauchy Goursat's theorem. However, how to prove when $a$ is inside or on the rectangle $R$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose $a$ with a small circle $C_t:|z-a|=t$ traversed in negative direction so that $\partial R\cup C_t$ encloses a domain where $f$ is holomorphic

(if you want you can add an edge $L$ joining $\partial R$ and $C_t$ so that $\partial R\cup L\cup C_t\cup L^-$ is the boundary of a simply connected domain)

then $$\int_{\partial R\cup C_t}f(z)dz=0$$
and $$\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{C_t}f(z)dz=0$$

since $f$ is continuous.